# async await retry log after all retries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

How can I console.log if it still fails after all retries done? and console.log if it succeeds, using [`async-retry`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-retry) package:

```
    const retry = require('async-retry');

    async function updateDB(updateUser) {
        await retry(async () => {
            const res = await updateUser;
            if (/* some error after finishing all retries*/) {
                console.log('failed');
            }
            console.log('Success');
        }, {
          retries: 5
        });
    }
```

how can this be achieved?

or in other words, how can I call another function (**function A**) only after all retries attempts failed? and call **function B** if it didn't throw at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const retry = require('async-retry');

    async function updateDB(updateUser) {
    try{ 
        const result =   await retry(async () => {
            const res = await Promise.all(updateUser).then(()=>{
              try{
                return  new Promise((resolve) => resolve('OK')),  {  retries: 5   }
              }catch(e){
                return  new Promise((resolve) => resolve('KO')),  {  retries: 5   };

              }
         });
         }
      );
    }catch(err){
        console.log('The function execution failed !')

      }

    }
```

Comment: why do you include three args for retry function, the library says it has two only

Answer (score 2):

you can use function onRetry, something like this

```
const retry = require('async-retry');

async function updateDB(updateUser) {
    await retry(async () => {
        const res = await test();
        console.log('Success');
    }, {
        onRetry: (err, number) => {
            console.log('attempt', number)
            if (number === 5) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        },
        retries: 5
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
const result = await retry(async () => {
    const res = await updateUser;
    if (/* some error after finishing all retries*/) {
        console.log('failed');
    }
    console.log('Success');
    return 'success';
}, {
    retries: 5
});
if (result != 'success') {
    console.log('all failed');
}
```

Comment: then do i still need that if line inside the retry with its console log failed??